# Why does money fly out when I die?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Sometimes when I get shot (killed) in Modern Warfare 3 (PS3), a plume of money shoots out of my player.  What is that all about?

Comment: It symbolizes your lost opportunity cost of having done something productive.

Comment: It's a natural physiological response for the body to empty the bladder, bowels and pockets to traumatic or fatal injury.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**"Payback"**, or when "a plume of money shoots out of [your] player", is when someone kills you that you previously killed (in multiplayer gameplay).